# Invalid reference format: Running Docker on MAC to have SQL Server 2019 in a container

Tags: sql-server, macos, docker, containers, sql-server-2019

I followed these steps in this link (https://database.guide/install-sql-server-2019-on-a-mac/) to install SQL Server 2019 on MAC.

I was able to pull the image down. using this command.

```
   sudo docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU6-ubuntu-16.04.
```

When I ran this command.

```
   sudo docker run -e “ACCEPT_EULA=Y” -e “SA_PASSWORD=testsql@123” -p 1433:1433 —name sql_server_2019 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU6-ubuntu-16.04
```

I got this following error.

> invalid reference format

I changed the quotes to single quote based on the results I found online and that did not work.
I tried several other password combinations but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: The quotes in the question look like Unicode "Smart Quotes". Does it work better if you use standard ASCII Quotes?

Comment: Also, try `--name sql_server_2019` (with two dashes) instead of `—name sql_server_2019` (which is Unicode Em Dash).

Comment: I tried both, removing smart quotes and using two dashes without much success.

Comment: I've resolved it by using a simpler name for the container. Instead of using sql_server_2019, I used Bart, the exact name used in the example.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a somewhat similar issue when I copied the command from the [MS website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-bash).

To make it work I had to remove double quotes:

```
docker run -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y -e SA_PASSWORD=Str0ngP@ssw0rd -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 -h sql1 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```